# Sharing content with other apps

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

I'm new to android. I've developed a library and integrated the same with two apps. And I have broadcast receiver for screen unlock in that library.and have stored unlock count in sharedpreferences. If the count is 2 then i ll show popup.and each application will be having its own private sharedpreferences. Whenever I receive unlock broadcast and the count is 2 then i'll show a pop up message.here, Since I have integrated the lib with two app,two popup msgs are coming up.I just want to show only one popup from any one of the app.I couldn't find a solution for this.How it can be achieved. any idea pls?

Thanks
Jeyanthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list the installed applications on the current device using the Package Manager, like this :

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
```

Then each PackageInfo contains the package name (com.yourname.package1, com.yourname.package2). You will also have the install and last update time (see the [PackageInfo reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html)).

Then you could on each of those app detect if another one exist and then have some kind of priority. For example, only the last installed app display a popup, or use a priority of your own (application A before application B).

Comment: You are simply great!Thank you so much for the idea!